# React Context: How do I pass an object array and display contents in Consumer?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects:

[image]

How can I display the content of objects in Consumer? I would like to place each object element in div. But I can't do it. That's what I'm doing right now.

my Provider:

```
  render() {
    const { basketItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <ShoppingBasketContext.Provider
        value={{
          basketItems
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ShoppingBasketContext.Provider>
    )
  }
```

and my Consumer:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ShoppingBasketContext.Consumer>
          {( {basketItems} ) => (
            <div className="shoppingBasket">
              {basketItems}
            </div>
          )}
        </ShoppingBasketContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`basketItems` is an array and you need to map over it to render

```
render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ShoppingBasketContext.Consumer>
              {( {basketItems} ) => basketItems.map((item, index) => (<div className="shoppingBasket" key={index}>
                  <div>{item.name}</div>
                  <div>Quantity: {item.quantity}</div>
                  <div>Price: {item.price}</div>
                </div>)
              }
            </ShoppingBasketContext.Consumer>
          </div>
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ShoppingBasketContext.Consumer>
          {( {basketItems} ) => (
            <ul className="shoppingBasket">
              {basketItems.map(item => (
                 <li key={item.name} className="shoppingBasketItem">
                   <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
                   <p>Quantity: {item.quantity}</p>
                   <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
                 </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </ShoppingBasketContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
```